# Complete reference to Gradle's Maven plugin

Tags: maven, gradle

I want to write a Gradle script, which generates a Maven `pom.xml` file.

Where can I find a reference or, better, the source code of the Gradle Maven plugin? I want to find out whether I can add `module` elements to a `pom.xml` file in Gradle (and if yes, how).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some useful resources:

- [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)
- [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)
- [Gradle Javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/)
- [Gradle Github repository](https://github.com/gradle/gradle) (search for `org.gradle.api.plugins.MavenPlugin`)

Also worth a look are the samples in the full Gradle distribution. You can also browse them in the GitHub repository (under `subprojects/docs/src/samples/maven`).